# How to filter data from a MySQL Database Table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, filter

I am trying to code a search box that will search though a column in my database. If the search matches the column then that record will be printed in the table below.

I am searching on a column that contains the county of a company record. There are no errors being displayed however when I search for a county that is in the database the table remains blank. I can't see what I have done wrong in theory I think the code should work! Any help would be appreciated.

**DBconnect.php**

```
<?php
// connect to the database
$db = 'stylecraft_dev';
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'stylecraft_admin';
$password = '000000';

$dbConn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die("Failed to connect to database");
$result = mysql_select_db($db, $dbConn) or die("Failure selecting database");
?>
```

**form.php**

```
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM member ";

            if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

                $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search-box']);

                $sql .= "WHERE MB_COUNTY = '{$search_term}' ";
            }

            $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            ?>

            <form name="search_form" method="POST" action="stockists.php">
            Search: <input type="text" name="search_box" value=" "/>
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search the stockists...">
            </form>

            <table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">

            <tr>
                <td><strong>Company Name</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Website</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Phone</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Address</strong></td>
            </tr>

            <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['MB_COMPANY'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['MB_MOBILE'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['MB_PHONE'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['MB_COUNTY'];?></td>
            </tr>

            <?php } ?>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
            $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);
            $sql .= "WHERE MB_COUNTY LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
```

The input name doesn't match - `search-box` versus `search_box`:

`$_POST['search-box']` and `<input type="text" name="search_box" value=" "/>`

You should try to echo `$search_term` and `$sql` for debugging.

Comment: Ah yes thankyou I have corrected this however the problem persists!

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo here

```
$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search-box']);
```

Must be according to your form

```
$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);
```

Comment: Ah yes thankyou I have corrected this however this has not fixed my problem!

Comment: Can you put an echo in the first if isset(), that echos out the country?

echo $_POST['search_box']

Check if it echos out the result you want. Then try manually querying it on phpmyadmin to see if it actually gives results.

Comment: @jonlloyd so right above the query, what does echo $sql give you? What if you copy that exact query and paste it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: When I go to run the query it produces an error I have not seen before!     SQL query: Documentation

$sql = "SELECT * FROM member ";

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$sql  =  "SELECT * FROM member "' at line 1

Comment: Here look at that it's not actually taking the value from $_POST search box. The query is not working because you got $sql in it as well. If you execute SELECT * FROM member it will work fine.

Comment: I have removed this and it produces another error - SQL query: Documentation

SELECT *
FROM memberif( isset(
$_POST[ 'search']
) ) {$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string(
$_POST[ 'search_box']
);

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
                
                $search_term = mysql_real_escape_strin' at line 3

Comment: @jonlloyd `SELECT * FROM member` can hardly be wrong...unless your table is not exactly named `member`, something like `Member` ?  In addition, do you have code to connect with database first?

Comment: Yes I have the connection file being called in the header and the table is 100% called member. The connection code is -                                      <?php
// connect to the database
$db = 'stylecraft_dev';
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'stylecraft_admin';
$password = '0000000';

$dbConn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die("Failed to connect to database");
$result = mysql_select_db($db, $dbConn) or die("Failure selecting database");
?>

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in the search box value.

```
<input type="text" name="search_box" value=" "/>
```

If that is not intentional for some reason and it is being submitted with search phrase then it may cause the search not succeeding, meaning if you are searching for "Mercedes" but submitting it with a space like " Mercedes" then it is not a  match because of the space.

You can either trim the search_term `$search_term = trim($search_term)` or just remove that space from `value=" "`.

Comment: Just noticed this was from 2 years ago. No idea how I ended up on this page.

Answer (score 0):

This was your code `$sql .= "WHERE MB_COUNTY = '{$search_term}' "`;

The correct code is `$sql .= " WHERE MB_COUNTY = '{$search_term}' ";`

**space between " and where clause is needed **